# Graph request fails in code but succeeds in browser

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a graph request to search for users and getting an NSError code of 5 when I make the attempt in code, however the exact same request when made from a browser succeeds and returns a list of search results.

Here's the code:

```
NSString* graphRequest = @"https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=somebody&type=user&access_token=<REMOVED>";

FBRequest *fbRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath: graphRequest];

[fbRequest startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *theError)
 {
```

Why might there be a difference in the code to a browser when the graph request is identical? I can make other graph requests (to find friends for example) without a problem - it is only this particular graph call that is causing problems.

(I've confimed the FBSession is open at the point of the FBRequest call, and am calling FBSession:setActiveSession)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're including the full URL you'd hit manually in `graphRequest`

You should only be including the API path, not the full server address and protocol identifier and you almost certainly shouldn't have an access token in the the path- check the docs for the iOS SDK if you're trying to migrate calls from another version of your app to the iOS version

The SDK should be managing your access tokens / sessions (in FBSession) and deciding which server and API version to call

Your example here should probably look more like:

```
NSString* graphRequest = @"search?q=somebody&type=user";

FBRequest *fbRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath: graphRequest];
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been using the full url with other graph calls and it has been working for months, for example using the following to fetch pictures: "full https url here (stack overflow is removing it from the comment for some reason)/https://graph.facebook.com/fbid/picture?type=square". Any idea why the other calls work with the full url but not this one? I'll shorted the other calls to be consistent.

Comment: There might be something in the SDK code detecting use of the full URL and stripping it out which fails here because the endpoint is only one level deep (/search instead of /me/something)